# Find the pattern of the time-series dataset through moving average

Tags: r, plot, extract, time-series, moving-average

I have both time series data and moving average data for the same data-set and the same time interval. I would like to extract the overlapping points. I would like extract those points where the extremum between the current and the last crossing point (intersected point between Moving average and time series) is taken depending on the direction of the trend reveral. I don't have idea whether perform it based on tables (1-Time series table includes temperature and timestamps 2-Moving average table includes only Moving average results of temperature) or perform it based on plot of them in which I have add moving average to time series plot.

Table of Time Series:

```
     ambtemp                  dt
1     -1.14 2007-09-29 00:01:57
2     -1.12 2007-09-29 00:03:57
3     -1.33 2007-09-29 00:05:57
4     -1.44 2007-09-29 00:07:57
5     -1.54 2007-09-29 00:09:57
6     -1.29 2007-09-29 00:11:57
7     -1.42 2007-09-29 00:13:57
8     -1.37 2007-09-29 00:15:57
9     -1.32 2007-09-29 00:17:57
10    -1.37 2007-09-29 00:19:57
11    -1.14 2007-09-29 00:21:57
12    -1.16 2007-09-29 00:23:57
13    -1.08 2007-09-29 00:25:57
14    -1.21 2007-09-29 00:27:57
15    -1.26 2007-09-29 00:29:57
16    -1.50 2007-09-29 00:31:57
17    -1.35 2007-09-29 00:33:57
18    -1.56 2007-09-29 00:35:57
19    -1.60 2007-09-29 00:37:57
20    -1.30 2007-09-29 00:39:57
21    -1.24 2007-09-29 00:41:57
22    -1.24 2007-09-29 00:43:57
23    -1.10 2007-09-29 00:45:57
24    -0.99 2007-09-29 00:47:57
25    -1.04 2007-09-29 00:49:57
26    -0.97 2007-09-29 00:51:57
27    -0.92 2007-09-29 00:53:57
28    -0.70 2007-09-29 00:55:57
29    -0.58 2007-09-29 00:57:57
30    -0.49 2007-09-29 00:59:57
31    -0.54 2007-09-29 01:01:57
32    -0.37 2007-09-29 01:03:57
33    -0.24 2007-09-29 01:05:57
34    -0.34 2007-09-29 01:07:57
35    -0.43 2007-09-29 01:09:57
36    -0.52 2007-09-29 01:11:57
37    -0.16 2007-09-29 01:13:57
38    -0.50 2007-09-29 01:15:57
39    -0.15 2007-09-29 01:17:57
40    -0.04 2007-09-29 01:19:57
41     0.00 2007-09-29 01:21:57
42    -0.08 2007-09-29 01:23:57
43    -0.30 2007-09-29 01:25:57
44    -0.14 2007-09-29 01:27:57
45    -0.06 2007-09-29 01:29:57
46    -0.02 2007-09-29 01:31:57
47    -0.25 2007-09-29 01:33:57
48    -0.33 2007-09-29 01:35:57
49     0.01 2007-09-29 01:37:57
50    -0.28 2007-09-29 01:39:57
51    -0.26 2007-09-29 01:41:57
52    -0.34 2007-09-29 01:43:57
53    -0.43 2007-09-29 01:45:57
54    -0.20 2007-09-29 01:47:57
55     0.19 2007-09-29 01:49:57
56     0.28 2007-09-29 01:51:57
57     0.07 2007-09-29 01:53:57
58    -0.32 2007-09-29 01:55:57
59    -0.20 2007-09-29 01:57:57
60    -0.42 2007-09-29 01:59:57
61    -0.40 2007-09-29 02:01:57
62    -0.54 2007-09-29 02:03:57
63    -0.67 2007-09-29 02:05:57
64    -0.42 2007-09-29 02:07:57
65    -0.57 2007-09-29 02:09:57
66    -0.73 2007-09-29 02:11:57
67    -0.54 2007-09-29 02:13:57
68    -0.70 2007-09-29 02:15:57
69    -0.70 2007-09-29 02:17:57
70    -0.58 2007-09-29 02:19:57
```

Table of Moving average:

```
  [1]      NA      NA      NA      NA      NA      NA      NA      NA      NA
 [10]      NA      NA      NA      NA      NA      NA      NA      NA      NA
 [19]      NA -1.3250 -1.3300 -1.3360 -1.3245 -1.3020 -1.2770 -1.2610 -1.2360
 [28] -1.2025 -1.1655 -1.1215 -1.0915 -1.0520 -1.0100 -0.9665 -0.9250 -0.8760
 [37] -0.8165 -0.7635 -0.6910 -0.6280 -0.5660 -0.5080 -0.4680 -0.4255 -0.3765
 [46] -0.3290 -0.2955 -0.2770 -0.2475 -0.2370 -0.2230 -0.2215 -0.2310 -0.2240
 [55] -0.1930 -0.1530 -0.1415 -0.1325 -0.1350 -0.1540 -0.1740 -0.1970 -0.2155
 [64] -0.2295 -0.2550 -0.2905 -0.3050 -0.3235 -0.3590 -0.3740 -0.3860 -0.3880
 [73] -0.3695 -0.4045 -0.4450 -0.4900 -0.5125 -0.5215 -0.5515 -0.5825 -0.6140
```

[image: Overlap of time series and moving average for different window size]
Overlap of time series and moving average for different window size

[image: Expected Results for window size of 40]
Expected Results for window size of 40

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Once you have the set-up right, it's an easy three step process.

Step 1: Use a serious time series package for this sort of stuff. I suggest `xts` -- it's awesome.

Step 2: Once you have it in this format, it's just a few lag commands, and a few logical tests.

Step 3: Index your data with the output of the logical tests.

The first problem is getting from your text file into R - i put a copy in my `~/Downloads/` directory, but yours may be elsewhere.  The problem with the text file is that you have only two headers, and four columns -- this will cause R problems. So let's skip the header row, and name them ourselves.

```
require(xts)
require(TTR)

dd <- read.table("~/Downloads/Timeseries.txt", skip=1)
dd <- dd[,-1] # cut off the row numbers

colnames(dd) <- c('ambtemp', 'date', 'time')

dt <- as.POSIXct(paste(dd$date, dd$time))
tempdata_x <- xts(dd$ambtemp, order.by = dt)
colnames(tempdata_x) <- 'ambtemp'

tempdata_x$ma20 <- SMA(tempdata_x$ambtemp, n=20)
```

max change:

```
max(diff(tempdata_x$ambtemp), na.rm=TRUE)
[1] 1.92

match(max(diff(tempdata_x$ambtemp), na.rm=TRUE), diff(tempdata_x$ambtemp))
[1] 357
```

So the row you want is number 357, get it via `tempdata_x[357,]`.

Check for overlaps / crossings etc:

```
tempdata_x$overlap <- ifelse(tempdata_x$ambtemp == tempdata_x$ma20, 1, 0)
tempdata_x$aboveMA <- ifelse(tempdata_x$ambtemp > tempdata_x$ma20, 1, 0)
tempdata_x$belowMA <- ifelse(tempdata_x$ambtemp < tempdata_x$ma20, 1, 0)
tempdata_x$crossUp <- ifelse(lag(tempdata_x$belowMA) & tempdata_x$aboveMA, 1, 0)
tempdata_x$crossDown <- ifelse(lag(tempdata_x$aboveMA) & tempdata_x$belowMA, 1, 0)
```

Now your data frame `tempdata_x` has a few new columns - which we'll use for indexing later.

A column *overlap* marked with 1 when `ambtemp == ma20`; *aboveMA* marked with 1 when `ambtemp > ma20`; *belowMA* marked with 1 when `ambtemp < ma20`; *crossUp* marked with a 1 when there is a crossing up from below, and another column *crossDown* market with a 1 when there is a crossing down from above.

Restrict to cases where there is a moving average (ie remove the leading section)

```
tempdata_x.trim <- tempdata_x[complete.cases(tempdata_x),]
```

Use the fact that the columns we created contain 0 and 1 -- and so can be coerced to logical to index `tempdata_x.trim`:

```
tempdata_x.trim[as.logical(tempdata_x.trim$overlap), 1:2]
tempdata_x.trim[as.logical(tempdata_x.trim$aboveMA), 1:2]
tempdata_x.trim[as.logical(tempdata_x.trim$belowMA), 1:2]
tempdata_x.trim[as.logical(tempdata_x.trim$crossUp), 1:2]
tempdata_x.trim[as.logical(tempdata_x.trim$crossDown), 1:2]
```

I tested each line on your 720 row text file -- it works.

Comment: I cannot fit my data to the code. So, I have updated the data in the question. I would appreciate it if you could give more details on  what you have done.

Comment: So it is a 20 period moving average?

Comment: Yes, exactly, It is for 20 number of records.

Comment: So i am going to call the data frame dd, with col names ambtemp and dt, with dt just a character string -- please tell me if that's a bad assumption.

Comment: When I  used this command : tempdata_x <- xts(dd$ambtemp, order.by = dt) . I have faced with this error :Error in xts(p29$ambtemp, order.by = dt) : 
  NROW(x) must match length(order.by)

Comment: This is hard without your dataset. Can you supply dim(foo) for both, or dput(foo)?

Comment: For time series: (720*2) and Moving average (720*1). I can send the data-sets to you.

Comment: please post them someplace.

Comment: @ali amidi -- i downloaded your data and edited the answer to show how to get from your text file into R. Your problem was with the number of text headers not matching the number of columns of data that the whitespace suggested to R's `read.table` function. If you have further problems reading in data, i suggest you ask another question. btw why did you un-accept this answer?